# How to check facebook sdk loaded properly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-likebox

I have a website which is integrated with facebook like-box, it is working fine (please check the code below)

### script after body

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

### inside sidebar

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/javatips.net" data-width="304" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
```

The problem is some networks proxy enabled and this will block facebook like-box and showing "page not found" message. In order to remove this message, I need to check whether like-box (Facebook SDK) is loaded properly or not, fb-like-box div should shown only if like-box (Facebook SDK) is loaded properly
Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hide elements with class `.fb-like-box` through your stylesheet, and make them visible again in the fbAsyncInit event that the SDK fires.